# How to speed up in Controller while loading multiple attributes

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

The problem that I come across is the loading speed in Controller using spring mvc framework. In a controller, I need to use `model.addAttribute("xx",xxxx)` for multiple attributes. Meanwhile, for each attribute, it contains lot of records in the database which leads to a very slow loading speed in view template. Hence, I am thinking that if there is any way that I can try to speed up my application

Comment: We need some more details. Are you using pagination in long lists?

Comment: @Neil McGuigan 
yes, I'm using the bootstrap datatable pagination plugin